# Set a variable in a Foundation's reveal modal - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, action

I'm trying to set a variable in a reveal modal with CakePHP.
The reveal modal i'm using is with Zurb Foundation

I have to generate a code and display it.
I have a HomeController with a generatecode() function.
In my Home.ctp I have a div with reveal modal (cf. Basic section [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html))
I have also a link button generate with that code :

```
echo $this->Html->Link('Unlock Link', array('action'=>'unlockpwd'), array('class' => 'button small', 'data-reveal-id' => 'modal_unlockpwd'));
```

Here is my action code :

```
function unlockpwd() {
        $this->set('code', $this->Function->generatePwdLock());
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

And in my Home.ctp, i just display $code in the reveal modal but i get an undefined variable error.

I think it's because i display the modal before i set $code.

How can I solve this problem ? I tried the setFlash, it works but the reveal modal seems better for the user.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set 'code' as a variable and redirect away from the page so the variable is lost. Solution would be to do:

```
function unlockpwd() {
    $this->Session->write('Code', $this->Function->generatePwdLock());
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

where you want to see it:

```
echo $this->Session->read('Code'); 
$this->Session->delete('Code'); //if you want to show only once
```

Comment: I tried your solution.
I don't have errors but nothing appears when i do Session->read('code').
Btw, when i try to use the Session->delete('code') i get this error : 
` Warning (512): Method SessionHelper::delete does not exist `

Comment: You have loaded only the session helper - it does not have the ability to write to session. you need the Session component. Load using: public $components = array('Session'); Suggestion would be to write it in AppController

Comment: Yep, my bad. I add the helpers Session in my  controller and still get the error 512. The code is displayed but is the same. I think it's not regenerate. I tried to use the Session->Delete directly in the controller function but no change

Comment: You need the session component, I changed my previous comment :)

Comment: I already have public $components = array('Session'); in my AppController. But still not work

Comment: Try adding 'Auth' component too

Comment: Already have Auth too lol

I notice something, Session->Delete still not work but when i open the link in a new tab, the action url load then i'm redirect with the referrer and the code is regenerated but the modal don't popup

I think the modal not load the page when it popups ...

Comment: I think you can do everything without redirection. If you want the code to be generated only once write cookies that the code is generated and that would solve it :) the redirection back to the page might be the problem

Comment: Maybe i will change for setFlash simply. Thanks for your help :)